# Reduce height of background colour of Text in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React Native Android App that has some highlighted words, I do that highlighting with the help of background color prop of Text Component. But the problem is the background colour height is too large that if the text has multilines then I want to show some space between highlighted text. But the default background color prop is completely adding background color to whole text.

[image]

As you can see in the sample image, the sample and background there should be some space between them, but it is not.

I tries to add padding, but still not works. Anyone know the solution for it?

The code what I have tried is:

```
<Text style={{color:'black', backgroundColor:'#F8C5C5', margin: 10, padding:10}}>
```

Comment: Add sample code which you have tried.

Comment: Hi @Pramod added sample image and code..

Comment: Have you tried by adding explicit line height : -> style={{lineHeight: 30}}